# Python 3.5: Dict value object does not support indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm getting an error in python 3.5 using this code. The error is `dict value object does not support indexing`.

```
#Find frequency of appearance for each value of the list
counter=collections.Counter(myList)
#Get frequencies' list
unique_freq = counter.values()
#Get unique items' list
unique_items=counter.keys()

probs= [(0,0)]*len(unique_items)

#Initialization of probs list
for i in range (0 , len(unique_items)):
        probs[i]=(unique_items[i],np.float32(unique_freq[i]))
```

Comment: Your code works without problem for me, i just used two arrays of same size as unique items and frequencies. You should check of what type() your arrays are.
EDIT: Additionally you could just do probs = [] and then pros.append((a,b)) instead of indexing.

Comment: You couldn't bother copying the full exception, nor telling us what types are bound to the names?

Comment: @MaxUppenkamp I edited my question.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I added more explicit code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast the .values() and .keys() results to list.

```
unique_freq = list(counter.values())
```

But the better, pythonic way of doing what you want to do is iterating the dictionary with items():

```
result = []

for key, value in your_dict.items():
    result.append((key,value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `dict.keys` and `dict.values` return *set-like* objects that don't support indexing.

In order to index them you need to change them to an object that supports it, usually a `list`:

```
#Get frequencies' list
unique_freq = list(counter.values())
#Get unique items' list
unique_items=list(counter.keys())
```